# I'm getting 'Module not found' error on Meteor, after an update

Tags: meteor

I'm getting errors even if I create a new project from scratch and try to run the same. Here is the error:

> While loading plugin compileTemplatesBatch from package templating:
> module.js:338:15: Cannot find module
> '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor' at
> Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at
> Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require
> (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.
> (C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\core-js\es6\object.js:12:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at
> Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.require
> (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.
> (C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\server.js:1:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at
> Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.require
> (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at npmRequire
> (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1665:14) at Module.useNode
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:453:20) at fileEvaluate
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:157:20) at require
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16) at
> meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.ecmascript-runtime.runtime.js
> (packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:24:18) at fileEvaluate
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9) at require
> (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16) at
> packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2832:15 at
> packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2845:3
>
> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with Meteor 1.3 on Windows, I think. Three packages seem to be the cause of this issue, `templating`, `ecmascript`, `standard-minifier-css`. They seem to not be working properly after an update. Try to follow these steps and be patient when Meteor is doing the download thingy and performing a proper install of the packages:

- Delete the `templating`, `ecmascript`, `standard-minified-css` folders in `C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local.meteor\packages`.
- Try to run meteor in your app folder again and wait for the packages being downloaded. (If this do not work properly, try using Powershell in admin mode).